# How to use using wpdb with fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Tags: php, wordpress, pdo, fetch-api

How to return search results with wpdb as if it were with (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)?

My problem is in this functions:

```
function expired_code($ID, $email){
    global $wpdb;
    $user = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT ID, activation_code, activation_expiry < now() as expired FROM wp_users_infor WHERE active = 0 AND ID = %d", $ID);
    if ($user) {
        if ((int)$user['expired'] === 1) {

        } 
    } 
}
```

I really don't understand the return of this type of research. How should I do to return this type of function for example?

```
function find_user_by_username(string $username) {
    $sql = 'SELECT user_email, password, active, email FROM wp_users WHERE user_email=:username';
    $statement = db()->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}
```

Would it be okay for me to use a foreach? Example:

```
function find_user_by_username(string $email) {
    global $wpdb;
    $user = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT user_email, password, active, email FROM wp_users WHERE user_email = %s ", $email);
    foreach ($user as $result) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `get_row()` as per [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#select-a-row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```php
function find_user_by_username( string $email ) {
global $wpdb;
$user = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_email, password, active, email FROM wp_users WHERE user_email = %s", $email ),
    'ARRAY_A'
);

foreach ( $user as $result ) {
    return $result;
} }
```

The option [ARRAY_A](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) produces an associative array for each row of the result.

Comment: @ryuunosuke.7003a Could you please mark the answer as correct? It will help others to know a correct answer is available when your question appears in their search results. Thanks.